# Proportional rescaling of background-image CSS HTML jQuery

Tags: html, css

i've used search but i haven't found proper answer for my question. I have web-page with 4 divs and 4 different background images with them. Every div has width property set to 100% and fixed height of 790px. The problem is that background images doesn't rescale properly on big screens (1200 and more).

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="screen1">
        <div id="screen-1-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="screen2">
        <div id="screen-2-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="screen3">
        <div id="screen-3-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="screen4">
         <div id="screen-4-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#screen1{
    width:100%;
    height: 790px;
    background-image: url(example);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#screen-1-wrapper{
    width: 960px;
}
/* difers only background-image */
```

I've tried background-size: cover and contain but it didn't work for me.
How can I solve that problem?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Can you demo the problem.

Comment: “background images doesn't rescale properly on big screens (1200 and more)” — what do you mean by “doesn't rescale properly”? Please describe what the images *are* doing, and what you *want* the images to do.

Comment: Here is the link with the problem background images: http://fit2day.knooow.ru/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-size: cover
```

would usually be my solution. Have you tried using it with the full vendor prefixes, e.g.

```
-moz-background-size:    cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-ms-background-size:     cover;
-o-background-size:      cover;
background-size:         cover;
```

Failing that, setting:

```
background-width:        100%;
background-height:       auto;
min-height:              790px;
```

would rescale the image responsively, but ensure it never dropped below the boundaries of the containing element.

Comment: Thank's a lot! min-height property saved the day:)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

if you use that the background image should be equal to the size and position of the div it's tied to in any resolution

Comment: It looks to me like that is the exact code he is using.. ?

Comment: he said he used it with cover and contain. setting it so 100% is a different story i believe. If not then i apologize.

Comment: Haha no need for apologies, take a look in the css code he posted ;)